# Set kendo DataSource without calling read()

Tags: javascript, jquery, listview, kendo-ui

Is it possible to set the DataSource of a Kendo ListView without having the DataSource then call the `read()` method?

I have a main DataSource that I am using on a ListView and all of the child ListViews but am just filtering it for each ListView depending on a few conditions. The way that I'm doing this is once all of the data has been bound to the main ListView then I create all of the child ListViews and assign the same datasource with filtering.

The issue I'm having here is once I assign the filtered DataSource to the new ListView it seems to be calling the read method again.

```
baSurveyGroupTemplateDataSource: new kendo.data.DataSource({
    transport: {
        read: {
            async: false,
            url: "/Url/to/data"
            dataType: "json",
            type: "GET",
            data: {
                id: $("#TemplateId").val()
            },
        }
    }
}),             
groupDataBound: function (e) {
    $(".childBaSuveyGroupTemplate").each(function () {
        viewModel.seedGroup(this);
    });
},
seedGroup: function (parentGroup) {
    var childrenGroupList = $(parentGroup);
    var parentGroupId = childrenGroupList.data("id");
    var childrenGroupDataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource(viewModel.baSurveyGroupTemplateDataSource);
    childrenGroupDataSource.query({
        filter: ({ field: "BaSurveyGroupTemplateParentId", operator: "eq", value: parentGroupId })
    });
    childrenGroupList.kendoListView({
        template: kendo.template($("#baSurveyGroupTemplateDisplayTemplate").html()),
        dataSource: childrenGroupDataSource
    });
}
```

Let me know if I need to clarify anything. It's hard to try and put what I'm doing and the problem I'm having into words.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding this to your ListView configuration:

```
autoBind: false
```

From the kendo documentation at http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/listview#configuration-autoBind

> If set to false the widget will not bind to the data source during
>   initialization. In this case data binding will occur when the change
>   event of the data source is fired. By default the widget will bind to
>   the data source specified in the configuration.
>
> Setting autoBind to false is useful when multiple widgets are bound to
>   the same data source. Disabling automatic binding ensures that the
>   shared data source does not make more than one request to the remote
>   service.

Then manually trigger the datasource read once you have everything set:

```
childrenGroupDataSource.read();  // "read()" will fire the "change" event of the dataSource and the widget will be bound
```